# How to add an image to an anchor tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to show an image with the link on the menubar. My code is as below:

```
  <a href="#" class="login" title="Login"></a>
```

The login class in css is as below:

```
   .login{background: url(../img/user.png) no-repeat 6px center;}
```

But, I am not able to view the image in the browser. If I tried like

```
   <a href="#" class="login" title="Login">Login</a>
```

then image appears in the background. But I want to use only image and not the text. how can I do that?

Comment: Remove the text and define a `width`. Or make the text transparent: `color: transparent`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas:...how? I am a complete noob..please explain

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll have to set dimensions on the `a` tag, and set it to `display: block;`.

```
.login {
  background: url(../img/user.png) no-repeat 6px center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

Of course replace dimensions with the correct ones.

Alternatively you could put the image directly into the `a` tag like so:

`<a href="#" class="login" title="Login"><img src="../img/user.png" /></a>`

Comment: If you add the image directly to the a tag like you have at the bottom of your answer, the anchor seems to overflow underneath the image a little bit. I'm currently trying to get rid of this bug in a site I'm working on. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2662333 Did you figure this out? I have the underline problem as well

Comment: @ducu Yes! I have it solved. I had posted a question on it and there are fiddles and code samples galore to look through. I hope it's a help to you. Please upvote it if it helps! Here's a link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864834/css-issue-with-jquery-ui-tabs/22865105#22865105

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following:

```
<a href="#" class="login" title="Login"><img src="../img/user.png" /></a>
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention this would mean you have to remove the background image from your CSS.

Comment: Won't the image be repeated with this approach? One through login class and other through img tag?

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention this would mean you have to remove the background image from the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

## 05 2021

### for SEO

Something to keep in mind when adding image wrapped with href element. If it is possible try to use the `img` inside the `href` element. This is good for seo. If the image fail to load it will show you the `alt` text.

> Whenever an image is linked, Google will use the text contained in the image's alt attribute as the anchor text. - moz

src: https://moz.com/learn/seo/anchor-text

When you wrap the `img` with the `href` element, always include the `alt` text.
This will act as a Anchor text to your `href` element.

```
<a href="#" class="login" title="Login">
    <img src="../img/user.png" alt="User profile"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```html
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand" title="Home"><img src= {require('../img/image_namer.svg')} /></a>
```